# How do I find the application to run a mms: wmv file in firefox?

Tags: firefox, vlc

I am attempting to stream movie files from my bases media center. When trying to open any of the movies using Ubuntu it wants me to choose an application.

I can't seem to select VLC or Movie Player.  It only allows me to choose obscure files within the VLC extension.

I am new to Ubuntu and do not know how to find the right application when asked.

I'm sure its an easy task but I can't seem to find the answer on any of the searches I have attempted.

Answer (score 0):

When the choose application dialogue open first double click on any folder (because we need to have a folder selected for the next bit).

Now press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, this will bring up a place for you to manually enter a file path. You should enter:

```
/usr/bin/vlc
```

and select with <kbd>Enter</kbd>